# Альтернативы к Console.Clear(); и к Environment.Exit(0); в C#

Tags: c#, .net

Нужно узнать альтернативы к **Console.Clear();** и к **Environment.Exit(0);** в C#.
Спасибо.

Comment: [Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили тщательный поиск ответа. Поделитесь результатом вашего поиска и расскажите, что вы нашли и почему найденные ответы вас не устроили. Это продемонстрирует вашу способность думать самостоятельно, поможет избежать повторяющихся очевидных ответов и, самое важное, увеличит шансы на получение точного ответа!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Чем Console.Clear не устраивает? Можно вызывать WinAPI методы, но это того не стоит, плюс можно поиграться с поток еще (не уверен).

Comment: Что сделать то хотите хотя бы? Консоль закроется сама и без них как только выполнит `return` в  `Program.Main`. Не нравится штатная очистка, заполните пробелами вручную.